# Refresh Activity when click in RecyclerView

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, kotlin

I have an activity made of 2 main items: a RecyclerView and a ListView. The RecyclerView acts as a filter and selecting/unselecting items in it will affect the contents of the ListView. Everything works well until I tried to implement the onClickListener on the RecyclerView and realised that's not an option.

I have tried going down the route of setting an OnClickListener inside the ViewHolder, but it needs to call a function inside the main activity and refresh it's listView. Any such interaction triggers the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:117)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:149)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:29)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:54)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:202)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:183)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:519)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:190)
    at .newsScreen._$_findCachedViewById(newsScreen.kt)
    at .newsScreen.filterNews(newsScreen.kt:71)
    at Cells.NewsFeedList$NewsSource$1.onClick(News Lists.kt:84)
```

Suppose it makes sense since I am trying to access UI from outside it's class, but I could not find alternatives to it.

**RecyclerView Adapter:**

```
class NewsFeedList() : RecyclerView.Adapter<NewsFeedList.NewsSource>() {
    private var source: List<NewsFeed> = ArrayList()

    constructor(s: ArrayList<NewsFeed>) : this() {
        source = s
    }

    class NewsSource : RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private var mTextView: TextView? = null

        constructor(v: View): super(v) {
            mTextView = v.title
        }

        fun bindInfo(news: NewsFeed, view: View, int: Int) {
            mTextView!!.text = news.title
            view.tag = int
            view.setOnClickListener { newsScreen().filterNews(view.tag.toString().toInt()) }
            if (news.selected) view.background = ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor(news.color))
            else view.background = ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor(design.backgroundColor))
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup?, viewType: Int): NewsFeedList.NewsSource {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent!!.context).inflate(R.layout.newsfeed_list, parent, false)
        return NewsSource(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: NewsFeedList.NewsSource, position: Int) {
        holder.bindInfo(source[position], holder.itemView, position)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return source.count()
    }

}
```

Then, inside my newsScreen class I need to access the RecyclerView adapter with new data

```
fun filterNews(i: Int) {

    newsFeed[i].selected = !newsFeed[i].selected
    filter.adapter = NewsFeedList(newsFeed)

}
```

If I remove any references to filter (RecyclerView), everything is fine, but the purpose of the onClickListener is to refresh the Activities content.

Is there any way to achieve this or should I change the RecyclerView to a different UI element?

**Edit:**
I have tried adding an OnClickListener to the RecyclerView but it does not seem to get triggered. **Code:**

```
filter.adapter = NewsFeedList(newsFeed)
filter.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@newsScreen, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)
filter.setOnClickListener { v: View? ->
       filterNews(v!!.tag.toString().toInt())
}
```

Comment: Why not use OnItemClickListener instead of OnClickListener?

Comment: Could you please check my updated question? I am not that familiar with Android so it might as well be something obvious that I'm missing.

Comment: I'm sorry, the OnItemClickListener actually doesn't work so well with RecycleView. I've written you an answer on how I'd solve the NullPointerException problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, here is another solution you can try:

Add this interface to your app:

```
interface ClickListener {
    void onItemClicked(int position);
}
```

Implement it inside your MainActivity (or whatever activity you have the buttons on).

Pass the reference of the interface inside your Adapter constructor:
    ArrayList mList;
    ClickListener listener;

```
public MyAdapter(ArrayList<NewsFeed> mList, ClickListener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}

@Override
public MyAdapter.NavViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.someL, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(v, listener);

}

public void getItemClicked(int position){
    mList.get(position);
}
```

Finally, inside you ViewHolder class:

```
class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements OnClickListener {

    TextView textView;
    ImageView imageView;
    ClickListener listener;

    ViewHolder(View itemView, ClickListener listener) {
        super(itemView);
        this.listener = listener;
        textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
        imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        textView.setOnClickListener(this)
    }

    @Override
    void onClick(View v) {
      listener.onItemClicked(getAdapterPosition());
    }
```

And finally inside your Activity (which implements ClickListener interface) you'll have to override void `onItemClicked(int position);` inside which you'll have your action.

P.S.: This answer was written with major help from user: https://stackoverflow.com/users/2667883/chaynik

Answer (score 2):

For your Adapter class you'll be having a ViewHolder class (probably as an inner class) which implements the OnClickListener as such in this code:

```
class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements OnClickListener {

    TextView textView;
    ImageView imageView;

    ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
        imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
    }

    @Override
    void onClick(View v) {

    }
}
```

Assuming your Adapter is not an inner class of your Activity class, if you are willing with onClick() to access your Activity class' methods/variables you MUST have the reference.

The preferable way is to pass the Context reference via the constructor of your Adapter, given your ViewHolder is an inner class of your Adapter:

```
class MyAdapter extends extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    Context context;

    MyAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements OnClickListener {

        TextView textView;
        ImageView imageView;

        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
            imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        }

        @Override
        void onClick(View v) {
            // Here we gain access to non-private methods/variables 
            // of the Activity, which Context reference we are holding.
            ((MyActivity) context).someMethod();
        }
    }
}
```

Hope, this helps.

Comment: That's what I did to get the error in the first place

Comment: Thank you, will update tomorrow when I'll get back to the machine

Comment: I have updated my question with code. Please note it's Kotlin, not Java, but syntax it's so similar I'm sure that won't be a problem :)

Comment: Alright, I've added 2nd answer, since I thought that 1st answer could be useful for someone else.. I hope is solves your problem.

Comment: I don't know why but this work. Thanks @SerjArdovic

Answer (score 1):

1. make a function reload() and reload the all views
2. pass your activity context using .this to adapter
3. in adapter, pass the context to the class object like

   ```
   MyActivity activity = (MyActivity)context
   ```

and call the method like:

```
activity.reload();
```